# Is it possible to make part of an html element below another element 'invisible'

Tags: html, css, reactjs, parallax

I have built a simple website which includes a parallax image gallery with accompanying text descriptions for each image. The gallery is underlaid with a simple repeating pattern wallpaper.

The images have no margin between them. Their borders are covered by the text box which has a higher z-index, and the discrepancy between the scroll speed of the images and texts creates the parallax effect.

I would like to allow the background wallpaper (bottom layer) to also be the background of the textbox but to achieve this, I would need to make the middle layer (the image) transparent where it is obscured by the text box.

I have no idea where to start with this - I suspect my best bet is to just ignore this problem remove the wallpaper altogether but perhaps there is a straightforward answer to this issue?

The included image has a semi-transparent text-box and borders to give an idea of the layout and the problem I'm facing. Would appreciate any ideas. thanks

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KE2B.png)

Comment: Please share what you have got so far!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.